# Set of points at which a continuous function is not locally Lischitz: It is measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Suppose I have a (uniformly) continuous real function on a closed interval. Is there anything intelligent I may say about the set of points at which the function is not locally Lipschitz? For example, can this set be uncountable? Can it have non-zero measure?

Comment: Take any continuous but nowhere differentiable function. It cannot be locally Lipschitz at any point in the domain due to [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem)

Comment: A lipschitz function is a.e differentiable. Consider a continuous, nowhere differentiable; then there is no interval on which it is Lipschitz.

Comment: It would probably be of interest if someone knows whether there is a Borel class characterization for $\{x \in [0,1]: \; f \; \text{is pointwise Lipschitz at} \; x\}$ and/or $\{x \in [0,1]: \; f \; \text{is locally Lipschitz at} \; x\}.$ Surely these sets are at most Borel class 2 or 3, but do we have a sharp result or does some other property need to be included to have sharpness for one or both of these sets?